# Define JavaScript function for multiple script tags

Tags: javascript, html, scope, script-tag

I have a function `f1()` defined within a given script `script1.js` and another function `f2()` which calls `f1()` in another script `script2.js`. I have included the scripts in my HTML file header like so:

```
<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>
```

I get a `ReferenceError`.

> f1 is not defined

Could anyone explain why? I guess the function is out of scope since it is in another script. I have included it above the calling function's script, but that did not seem to work. I read something about namespacing, but I don't believe this should be that complicated. Any suggestions?

Comment: They are both loaded into the same namespace. Can you show how `f1()` is declared?

Comment: *"Could anyone explain why? "* Not without seeing the source code.

Comment: There is clearly more to this than u provided, they WILL work the way you described, you're just not telling us something.

Comment: You were, in fact, right. I had a character at the end of the `script1.js` which I didn't see, resulting in a syntax error. The above mentioned does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a character at the end of the `script1.js`, which I didn't see, resulting in a syntax error.